# Unable to connect to source server in azure migration service

Tags: azure

I am unable to connect to source server in azure migration service.
I am doing a POC for migrating SQL Server database to Azure using the Azure Migration Service. I followed the steps in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-managed-instance-online).

But when I create the New Migration Project and specify the source instance it gives me an error,

> Error 53 - SQL connection failed.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   The network path was not found

The SQL server is on my local machine itself.

Do I need to create some VM to connect to the source server. I understand I am missing some step but I did a lot of research but can't find a link to get it resolved.

Comment: What did you specify in the option for `Source SQL Server instance name`? Since the SQL server is on your local machine, I suspect NAT-ing may be the cause for the error.

Comment: I used DESKTOP-LKCMNKF as the instance name. Also since that didn't work so I tried providing the IP address of my machine (After reading few articles).

Comment: Yes, that will not work. Providing your IP may not be useful either since it most likely is a private IP that is not publicly visible.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai Any idea on how I can go ahead on this? If in case I am using a named instance source server of my organization, what steps I need to take care of while creating a migration project under the service. ?

Comment: As long as your server is reachable through the internet and you are following the documentation, you should be good.